# T[x] Euclidean if and only if T is a field.

Tags: polynomial-rings, euclidean-domain

I am for the first time teaching Algebra 1 practicals. With students, we were proving that

```
If T is a field, then the ring of polynomials T[x] is Euclidean
```

Now I know that the opposite is not true, because if T is not a field, T[x] is not even P.I.D. I would like to prove this statement in class, but I do not know any accessible proof (my proof is by investigating whether the factor-rings of R[x] are Artinian ).

One can easily show, that if R has a non-invertible  element $a\neq 0$, then the Euclidean norm from T[x] (degree of polynomial plus 1) wouldn't work as shown by the division of polynomials $x:ax$.

But I do not know how to prove that any other norm will also fail to be Euclidean.  I have never actually constructed such proof. When I was disproving Euclideaness I always disproved some weaker property (e.g. I proved that the ring is not even P.I.D.).

I am not sure whether elementary proof exists, but I feel that there should be one. Do you have any idea?